# Programmatically setting IIS6 Wildcard application maps

Tags: asp.net, deployment, msbuild, iis-6

I'm currently supporting a build process and I need to set the Wilcard Application maps on an iis6 website.

I currently utilise a mixture of the SDC tasks And the MSBuild Extension pack to do various things but I have come upon a brick wall when trying to set Wildcard Application Maps using these two frameworks.

perhaps I've just missed it in the documentation but I wondered if anyone knew how to set these.

To be clear here is where you would set these in the gui:

I am open to alternative methods of setting this including perhaps writing some code to do it if neccessary :)

[image: ApplicationMaps]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Wix, you can add those by using [WixIISExtensions](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/iis_xsd_index.htm):

```
<iis:WebApplicationExtension CheckPath="no"
         Script="yes"
         Executable="[FRAMEWORKROOT]v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll"
         Verbs="GET,HEAD,POST"/>
```

Also, as suggested in this [post](http://forums.iis.net/p/1163206/1927405.aspx#1927405), try:

```
String strPath = "IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root";
DirectoryEntry IISEntry = new DirectoryEntry(strPath);
PropertyValueCollection applicationMappings = IISEntry.Properties["ScriptMaps"];
applicationMappings.Add(@",%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll,4,All");
IISEntry.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: Unfortunately wix doesn't help me, allthough this is exactly what i am trying to acheive, I have noticed that the MSBuildExtensionPack does have a ScriptMaps section under its create task unfortunately I'm using SDC tasks to create the site, I may have to migrate to the Extension method which is less maintainable due to its formatting in script, unless anyone knows of an sdc method, the other prossible answer is to script it with something like Powershell

Comment: I think Powershell can help you in IIS7: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/437/powershell-snap-in-advanced-configuration-tasks/. Maybe in IIS6 but not sure. Otherwise, maybe create your own MSBuild Extension task using the c# code.

Comment: Also, have you looked at Iis6ServiceExtensionFile Class: http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.3.0/index.html

Comment: the very first entry you entered turned out to be the easiest solution I rolled a very basic MSBuild task to do the work i needed , I lookedup the path of the site I needed from the metabase and placed an asterisk before comma before %Windir%, worked a treat.. thanks for pointing me in the right direction. My google skills need improoving :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the msbuild extension pack you can do:

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Web.Iis6VirtualDirectory TaskAction="Create"  Website="site" Name="vdir" Properties="ScriptMaps=*,$(MSBuildToolsPath)\aspnet_isapi.dll,1,All"/>
```

This will replace all the script maps, not add one.